# readAsArrayBuffer cordova windows

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugin-file

I have used this example to create a working file upload from my Cordova Android client directly into Azure blob storage: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/

I would like to compile my app for Windows 10 too, but the Cordova docs say that Windows does not support readAsArrayBuffer. What can I do instead of using readAsArrayBuffer? I will be uploading large files (video) so the chunking is important.

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that to upload direct to blob storage you should use the Azure Storage JavaScript client library. Samples here: https://dmrelease.blob.core.windows.net/azurestoragejssample/samples/sample-blob.html
Worked a treat for me using cordova/windows